# Is “à l’hiver” acceptable?

Tags: grammaire

I listened to Pense à moi - France Gall. In the lyrics, I found “Pense à la neige à l’hiver.” I wonder if this is grammatically correct, although I know songs may use incorrect terms to adjust to the rhythm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bonsoir,

It is correct but there should be a comma in the sentence "Pense à la neige, à l'hiver". 
She means "Think about the snow, about winter".

To be correct without a comma you would say "Pense à la neige **en** hiver", meaning "Think about the snow in winter"

Comment: Merci beaucoup! That’s what I’ve never imagined. Thank you for your speedy answer!

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that "*à l'automne*" can be correct in some contexts.

> *L’emploi de la préposition à est également possible dans des contextes différents. La préposition à nous fait voir la saison comme un point sur l’axe du temps, le moment du temps où se situe l’événement évoqué dans la phrase.*

[Source](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3516)

> Brigitte et Denis emménageront dans leur nouvelle maison à l'hiver.

> La réfection des principales artères de la ville sera terminée à l’été 2007.

And it's always *au* with *printemps*.

However in this case I think it's to be interpreted like PAntoine suggested.